# Ionic Capacitor camera plugin

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

i'm using Ionic with Capacitor and camera plugin,
it's work fine on native mobile(Android), but i want to be able work with local(server on Chrome), but i'm getting the following error:
[image]

The following steps already done:

- npm install @ionic/pwa-elements
- defineCustomElements(window); in Main.ts
- Plugins.Camera.requestPermissions(); in my camera service.

I wrote my code based on the [Capacitor blog](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/ionic-framework-app)

The only thought that comes to mind is, it's appear because i'm using desktop computer and i don't have a camera, but if so how can i handle it?

Any suggestion will blessed:) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because there is no Camera. "Requested device not found" means the Camera was not found.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So what's is the right way to work with local (chrome)? Meanwhile i made an hidden file input, and in case of platform is web, I'm clicking on it from the component and open the chrome file picker. But I'm not quite sure if it's the right way

Comment: There is no right way, it depends in what you want. Camera plugin is supposed to use the camera, so if there is no camera it should fail, but if you want to show a file picker when there is no camera that’s ok.

Comment: Yes, maybe the right term that im looking for is file picker for both platform

Comment: But anyway thanks for you time, i will probably write some plugin for file picker because i didn't find any.